# Start animation in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport

I'm trying to make an animation that I've created start when in the screen's viewport.

```js
// Returns true if the specified element has been scrolled into the viewport.
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);

  // Get the scroll position of the page.
  var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
  var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  // Get the position of the element on the page.
  var elemTop = Math.round($elem.offset().top);
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
  var $elem = $('.image-container')

  if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
    // Start the animation
    $elem.addClass('start');
  } else {
    $elem.removeClass('start');
  }
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function() {
  checkAnimation();
});
```

```css
/* slide reveal aniamtion */

@keyframes left {
  0% {
    transform: translatex(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatex(0%);
  }
}


/* animation */

.animated-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
  transform: translatex(-100%);
}

.start {
  animation: left 2s ease-out forwards;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animated-container">
  <div class="image-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, the class does not seem to be applying to the container box when in view and is returning an error. Can anyone help me out with what's going wrong on this and why it what could be stopping the javascript from adding the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 68 (the first line in your `checkAnimation` function) reads `$(".image-container');`. Note how you've used double quotes to start the string, but a single quote to end it.

Just change that to `$('.image-container')` and you should be fine :)

---

**EDIT**. So, now you've fixed the above problem, but `$` is not defined. You're using `$(element)` but you haven't defined what `$` does or means. How about linking jQuery to your project? Or at least define `$` to be shorthand for the querySelector function?

---

**EDIT 2**. Okay, now it throws no errors, but it just doesn't work. Well, it actually does add the `.start` class - the start class alone though is not enough to start the animation. Your css file adds the animation on elements with `.left.start`, so either change that to trigger on only the `.start` class or add the `.left` class just like you add the `.start` class.

Comment: I've updated the snippet and it still seems to be giving off an error?

Comment: I'm going from the following js fiddle and it seems to be working okay on there but not for me? http://jsfiddle.net/5RNhL/225/

Comment: I adressed that issue. Add jQuery to your page or define `$` to work the way you intend it to work without it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very fresh with anything to do with javascript. I have tried adding the jquery repository (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js) but still have had no progress

Comment: I edited my question to address the new problem. It should work now. Cheers!